# GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo values look invalid

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I'm using `GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo` notifications to track GC events. It's nice, but looks like the output is invalid. I expect that `getGcInfo().getMemoryUsageBeforeGc() -> MemoryUsage.getUsed()` will report particular segment usage before running current GC. 
But it is always equal to `getGcInfo().getMemoryUsageAfterGc()` from previous notification. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the I use and it is working :) I mean I get correct numbers both before and after GC.

```
public synchronized void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback) {
    if (GARBAGE_COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION.equals(notification.getType())) {
      GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo info = from((CompositeData) notification.getUserData());

      com.sun.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean mxBean = (com.sun.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean) handback;
      GcInfo gcInfo = mxBean.getLastGcInfo();

      if (gcInfo != null) {
//use gcInfo.getMemoryUsageBeforeGc() and gcInfo.getMemoryUsageAfterGc()
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikem! I'm using remote JMX and handle is always null, so I'm using GcInfo retrieved from GCNI info object. And for example for Survivor space after is always the same as next notification before.

Comment: Just noticed that the problematic values are only for survivor spaces which makes sense, as objects are moved here only during GC's :/

Comment: Is is possible to not get GC notification with this code? In my case handleNotification is not being called.